# Can't open Cisco Packet Tracer on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: networking, 19.04, cisco

When I launch the Cisco Packet Tracer, I encounter the following error.

```
$ sudo packettracer
Starting Packet Tracer 7.2.1
/usr/local/bin/packettracer: line 8:  9348 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ./PacketTracer7 "$@" > /dev/null 2>&1
```

What could be the issue? How do I solve this?

Comment: i'm also too bro

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to install Cisco Packet Tracer 7.3 on Ubuntu 20.04 \[SOLVED\]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1232853/unable-to-install-cisco-packet-tracer-7-3-on-ubuntu-20-04-solved)

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem but I found the solution.
Cisco released a new version PT 7.2.2. Install the new version and if the problem still persists, you have to install a newer version of libpng12 (1.2.54) https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libpng12-0/download

Answer (score 0):

Gollis' answer didn't work for me. (I tried reinstalling 7.2.2 and installing the recommended version of libpng12).

Installing 7.3.0 worked though.