# Looking for qt-at-spi for ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, 20.04, qt

Package *packettracer* is referring to [Cisco Packet Tracer 7.3](https://www.netacad.com/portal/resources/packet-tracer).
My OS is Ubuntu 20.04.

I installed packettracer, but the package requires a *qt-at-spi* package that I could not find in the Ubuntu 20.04 repository.

```
$sudo dpkg -i PacketTracer_730_amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package packettracer.
(Reading database ... 199702 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../PacketTracer_730_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking packettracer (7.3.0) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of packettracer:
 packettracer depends on qt-at-spi; however:
  Package qt-at-spi is not installed.
dpkg: error processing package packettracer (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.15-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 packettracer
```

I searched for that package, but what I found is only [*qt-at-spi* for ubuntu 18.04](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qt-at-spi).
I tried to install it, but it also requires other packages.

```
$ sudo dpkg -i qt-at-spi_0.4.0-8_amd64.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package qt-at-spi:amd64.
(Reading database ... 202991 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../qt-at-spi_0.4.0-8_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking qt-at-spi:amd64 (0.4.0-8) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qt-at-spi:amd64:
 qt-at-spi:amd64 depends on libqt4-dbus (>= 4:4.8.0); however:
  Package libqt4-dbus is not installed.
 qt-at-spi:amd64 depends on libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8~); however:
  Package libqtcore4:amd64 is not installed.
 qt-at-spi:amd64 depends on libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8~); however:
  Package libqtgui4 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package qt-at-spi:amd64 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 qt-at-spi:amd64
```

I searched again for those other packages (libqt4-dbus, libqtcore4, libqtgui4), but what I found is only for Ubuntu versions below 20.04 (i.e 18.04, 19.04, 19.10), there are none for Ubuntu 20.04.

I keep trying to install those packages, but they depend on other unavailable packages again, and so on.

I have tried to install [Qt-5](https://wiki.qt.io/Install_Qt_5_on_Ubuntu). Qt-5.12.8 installed but I still did not get the *qt-at-spi* package.

Packettracer doesn't even seem to need *qt-at-spi*, as it runs properly without error. However, when I tried to install another package (whatever is it), there is a dependency error:

```
packettracer : Depends: qt-at-spi but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

So, I must run "apt --fix-broken install" first and uninstall packettracer before I can install another package. Then when that another package installed, I reinstall the packettracer again. It is annoying.

```
$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  packettracer
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
```

The question is:

- **Can you help to find qt-at-spi for ubuntu 20.04?** or
- **Can I exclude packettracer from apt --fix-broken install?**

Comment: Qt4 is EOL & unsupported upstream (2015 upstream though Debian & Ubuntu supported it until 15-Mar-2019) which is why it started to be removed entirely in 2019 in the *eoan* & *focal* cycles (refer https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/removing-qt-4-from-ubuntu-before-the-20-04-release/12295). The app if maintained should have been ported to Qt5 (introduced 19-Dec-2012)  Cisco need to re-package their tool for a supported Qt5

Comment: Thanks @guiverc , I have installed Qt-5.12.8 but why still did not get qt-at-spi package?

Comment: `qt-at-spi` was a Qt4 package with requirements for depreciated qt4 packages. That package doesn't exist in the Qt5 world. It's README starts "*This is a Qt 4 plugin that bridges Qt's accessibility API to AT-SPI2.*"  https://salsa.debian.org/a11y-team/qt-at-spi/-/blob/master/README   As stated it should be re-packaged by Cisco (ie. raise a bug with them to do it & wait), or an empty package created in a PPA that does nothing for *focal* but meets the dependency requirement..  Just my thoughts/2c

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to install Cisco Packet Tracer 7.3 on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1232853/unable-to-install-cisco-packet-tracer-7-3-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow these steps :

```bsh
cd Desktop
mkdir working-dir
cd working-dir
cp ~/Downloads/PacketTracer_730_amd64.deb .
ls
wget http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/d/double-conversion/libdouble-conversion1_3.1.0-3_amd64.deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libj/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg-turbo8_2.0.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libj/libjpeg8-empty/libjpeg8_8c-2ubuntu8_amd64.deb
ls -l
chmod +x *
ls -l
sudo dpkg -i *
sudo featherpad /var/lib/dpkg/status #featherpad here, is my text editor
    #ctrl+f (search) > Depends: libdouble-conversion1, qt-at-spi > (delete-this-line) > save & close
sudo apt --fix-broken install
packettracer
```

I also put a video on YouTube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5FuBKG49bIY it shows the same process but could be more helpful.

Comment: I would recommend you clean up your instructions, most of that is not necessary. All you need is one `mkdir`/`cd` to have an empty work directory if you want, then one `wget` to download the .deb files, and `dpkg` to install them (no need for chmod). After that, you shouldn't use featherpad or other GUI editors with `sudo` in general, something like `nano` or `vim` would be more appropriate. Running GUI applications as root can cause problems. Also better not delete the whole `Depends:` entry, but only remove the `qt-at-spi` entry from it, leave the other dependency relations intact!

Comment: Thank you, it's works.

Comment: You're welcome :D

Comment: Thank you Byte Commander :D

Comment: This didn't fix my problem, unfortunately.

Comment: Worked. Thanks. (Hope this is the normal thing to do.)

Comment: Why don't I seem to have the --fix-broken available to me?

Answer (score 0):

On 20.04 focal. No dependency issues except for qt-at-spi.

In the directory where you downloaded *PacketTracer_730_amd64.deb*:

```
sudo dpkg -i *
sudo vi /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Use `/` to search, and type `qt-at-spi`.

Use `x` to delete ", qt-at-spi", then `<shift>:wq` to write/save and quit.

`sudo apt --fix-broken install`

Thank you all!